# Vue i18n Unterminated Strings

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, vue-i18n

Getting issue with `Message compilation error: Unterminated closing brace` and `Message compilation error: Unbalanced closing brace` for Mustache's in Vue i18n which I even set variable data.

```
<page
    :intro="$t('/car details/intro new model', {'vehicle-model': 'Toyota',})"
    :loading="loading"
  >
    ....
  </page>
```

Which translates to: `/car details/intro new model: Nice that you are going to test drive the {vehicle-model}!`

I have tried to create a parser that replaces the said mustache but I think the issue lies within the `$t` of the Vue i18n

Comment: vehicle-model isn't a proper variable name in JS. You could start with not using it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the values within the curly braces as a single word, for example, `{vehicleModel}` ? I have encountered this issue before, and using this approach solved the problem for me.